# How can I test my SC2 Maps without a Battle.NET connection

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there any way to test my SC2 custom map while I cannot log on to Battle.NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a button within the Starcraft 2 Galaxy Editor: "Test Map" or the like, that will automatically launch the game and the custom map. As far as I know, that functionality doesn't require access to the internet (because it was still doable during the downtime between beta phases, where the beta servers themselves were offline.)

Comment: simply drag-and-drop the SC2Map-file onto SC2.exe also works =)

Comment: It still works but: You can play only alone and you have no lag/delay. Microing marines is way easier this way :)